# React Native: KeyboardAvoidingView not animated

Tags: animation, react-native, keyboard, textinput, react-animated

Is there anything special to do to make the view slide up when the keyboard appears ?
According to all the examples i have seen, it does it by default, but on my side it goes from point A to point B directly.

Here's my render where FadeInView is just an Animated.View:

```
<FadeInView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    style={s.container}
    contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center'}}
    behavior="position"
    keyboardVerticalOffset={-80}
  >
    <View style={{
      width: 100, height: 100, borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#E0E0E0', marginBottom: 30,
      }} />
      <Item>
        <Input
          placeholder={t('login:username')}
          onChangeText={(username) => { username = username.trim(); return this.setState({ username }); }} />
      </Item>
      <Item style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <Input
          secureTextEntry={true}
          placeholder={t('login:password')}
          onChangeText={(password) => { password = password.trim(); return this.setState({ password }); }} />
       </Item>
       isFetching ?
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                disabled={true}
                                style={cs.button}
                                onPress={() => this.onLogin()}>
                                <Text>{t('common:loading').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            :
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                activeOpacity={0.7}
                                style={cs.button}
                                onPress={() => this.onLogin()}>
                                <Text style={cs.buttonText}>{t('login:login').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                        {errorMessage != null &&
                            <Text style={cs.errorMessage}>{errorMessage}</Text>
                        }
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </FadeInView>

And the container style:

    const s = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingTop: 50,
            paddingRight: 20,
            paddingLeft: 20,
        },
    });
```

Sorry for the big code but i'm a bit desperate with this issue... Thanks!

Comment: It can be possible that it's your code error but most of the time it's problem of `KeyboardAvoidingView` itself. check this link : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8855
I have switched to https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.